# What does := mean when used in pseudocode?

Tags: set, pseudocode, a-star

When looking at pseudocode (actually, on the Wikipedia article on A*), i came across the use of := to assign or initialize a variable. What does this mean? Is part of some kind of set notation? If it's something complicated, how would one go about implementing this in C++ or Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:=` indicates [assignment of a variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29). `:=` is used when `=` is a test for equality (rather than the standard `==` seen in most modern programming languages), not an assignment. In [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29), for instance, `:=` is used for assignment, and `=` is used to test for equality. See [the "Notation" section of the assignment article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Notation) for a list of notations for assignment.

Comment: So := is just =, when = means ==? That makes some sense